# Using Amazon S3 to revolutionize how real estate shares information with people interested

Tags: email, amazon-s3, embed, file-sharing, infusionsoft

Right now we are using Dropbox to share "investor packages" with people who sign up for information on any given project on our website.

They sign up, get an email with a dropbox link, they get sent to a dropbox folder with all the files of information regarding that project.

This is automated through infusinosift, however we have manually set up each email in infusionisft because we had to paste the unique dropbox url into each email.

As more information becomes available (prices, floor plans etc) for that project, we add it to the dropbox folder. Then we MANUALLY send out a broadcast telling everyone something has been added.

With hundreds of different projects going on at the same time, this is difficult. Also Dropbox makes people think they need to download the app to view the files, which deters them from opening the information.

**Here's what we would like to do and plan on doing. BUT I NEED YOUR HELP**

1. Switch over to Amazon S3. Move all our condo investor packages over.
2. Make it as easy as possible for someone to access the information they sign up to.

**3. Everytime we add something new to a folder (or bucket) we want that person to be notified via email so they are reminded to check it out.**

So the the big thing here is public sharing with Amazon S3, and bucket update notification.

Customers **do not** need to edit or upload anything... so we don't want them to have those permissions. They just get the link and view the stuff, and be notified via email if something else is added to the folder.. pings if you will.

**BONUS**
Is there any way to embed buckets into a web page (kind of like Google Drive)??

**CREATIVITY**
Any suggestions or comments or feedback regarding this process and what I want done would be greatly appreciated. HOWEVER, if you have some other way of doing this, or can think of a workflow that would be super easy for customers to get the information they are looking for and be notified of the most recent info as soon as its available (or we add it into the folder), by all means please let me hear it.

Thank for reading through and for your help in advance!

Alexander

Comment: Not sure what type of answer you are looking for? More technical details? Are you a developer? You could probably keep stuff in infusionsoft and use the infusionsoft api to rig something up.

Comment: Although what you are proposing sounds like it could be implemented with S3 as one of its component parts (experience suggests that Dropbox, itself, uses S3), S3 is a low-level building-block component and your application would require significant additional code; however, having said that, what you are asking for here does not seem to be a well-defined "programming question" within the scope of this site.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! Basically we want some sort of automated notification system set up. So everytime i add a new file to the bucket, anyone who has associated themselves with that bucket is notified via email of the new file added.